# create a pdf file from a byte array returned by a .net webservice

Tags: php, .net, web-services, pdf

hi am a c# programmer with basic knowledge on php. Currently am working on a php assignment which requires a pdf to be downloaded. i tried downloading through webservice but it does not work. Am able to get the byte array of the concerned PDF. Is it possible to convert it in to a PDF file. Please help thank you.

my php code:

```
   <?php
    require_once("nuSOAP/lib/nusoap.php");
    $client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/WS-PDF/Fill_Pdf.asmx?wsdl',true);
    $soapaction = "http://tempuri.org/GetPdf";
    $namespace= "http://tempuri.org/";
    $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
    $params = array('test' => "PDF");
    $result = $client->call('GetPdf',$params,$namespace,$soapaction);
    print_r(array_values($result));
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: A file is just a stream of bytes. You should be able to save that array to a disk file and open it as a PDF. Provided, of course, that the bytes you received represent a valid PDF file.

Comment: @JimMischel can you please provide me some example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you assign the byte's to a variable then tell the browser to output a pdf you should get the pdf back. In the example below I use the variable $pdf.

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: $length");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='$filename'");
echo $pdf;
```

Comment: o right thats the length of the file, you can use this function to get that information filesize();

Comment: it seems to return the file size.. should i be using the array variable instead of file name to get size? since am creating a new file

Comment: if its returning exactly the same file then i would just use the file location.